# Is there a token future market on Ethereum?

Tags: tokens, exchanges

I was wondering if there is something similar to Cryptoderivatives but structured as a future exchange, maybe using the block number as the timeframe?

I couldn't find any.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Ethereum Stack Exchange as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'm simply asking for existing contracts that work as futures. I have no clue on how to make it less opinion-based since I'm asking for any example.

Comment: May be [r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/) is a better place for your question.